# Bootstrap Grid Dimensions on form-group div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to clean up a pretty formidable layout which uses Bootstrap 3 and tabs in an AngularJs app.

I'm pretty familiar with most of the Bootstrap rules (e.g. nesting rows etc.), but there is one combination which I have not yet seen. Take the following snippet

```
<div class="tab-pane ng-scope active" ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" ng-class="{active: tabset.active === tab.index}" uib-tab-content-transclude="tab">
    <div class="tab-top-buffer ng-scope">
        <div class="row">
            <ng-form name="patientDetailsForm" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-date">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-question-circle" title="Enter the first three letters of the patient’s surname"></i></span>
                            <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                            <span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="" placeholder="Enter given name" ng-model="editModel.breastData.episode.patient.name" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="3" class="ng-pristine form-control ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched">
                        <!-- ngIf: patientDetailsForm.name.$invalid && patientDetailsForm.name.$touched --></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-question-circle" title="Enter the patient’s date of birth as day, month and four digit year of birthdate to be separated by a forward slash (/)."></i></span>
                            <label for="dob" class="control-label">DOB:</label>
                            <span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i></span>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty ng-valid-date ng-valid ng-valid-required" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ng-model="$parent.$parent.dob" is-open="dobPopup.opened" datepicker-options="dobDateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" ng-change="$parent.$parent.validateDob()" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" required="required"><div uib-datepicker-popup-wrap="" ng-model="date" ng-change="dateSelection(date)" template-url="uib/template/datepickerPopup/popup.html" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty"><!-- ngIf: isOpen -->
    </div>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDobPopup()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- ngIf: patientDetailsForm.dob.$invalid && patientDetailsForm.dob.$touched -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Is it legal (not bad practice) to add grid dimensions to the div which contains the `form-group` class. E.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"> ...
```

It seems to work, but it doesn't feel right. I just wanted to seek clarification to see if this was, in fact, a bad idea, in which case, I'll probably have to create a wrapping div.

Thanks

Comment: Id personally create a wrapping div and looking at my code on websites I've done I always have.... But I mean If you don't want to and It works I couldn't see a reason why not....

Comment: @ThomasWithers Thanks. The **only** argument against a wrapping div is clutter. More indenting etc. But I value your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with that Indeed it does add clutter. But I guess you can mark it down to the individual Developer/Situation